# SBCL installation in linux

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

How to install sbcl in os linux for a freshman of lisp.

I found just use the command
sh install.sh 
the error info is:
src/runtime/sbcl not found, aborting installation

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the Debian or Ubuntu distributions, you can install SBCL from their repositories: just type   `sudo apt-get install sbcl`.

Answer (score 2):

What flavor of linux?

If you use a popular distribution, e.g., debian, ubuntu, fedora, &c, then sbcl comes prepackaged: `aptitude install sbcl` or `yum install sbcl`.

Comment: RedHat Linux. The apt and yum command has been forbidden in the os. So the only way to install is to download the source or the binary to install.

Answer (score 1):

As it says on [SBCL's download page](http://www.sbcl.org/platform-table.html), if you have git access, you can run the command `git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/sbcl/sbcl` to get the development version to compile from.

To get the binary alone, you may use the following commands depending on your CPU architecture:

x86

```
wget --trust-server-name http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sbcl/sbcl/1.0.58/sbcl-1.0.58-x86-linux-binary.tar.bz2?r=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sbcl.org%2Fplatform-table.html&ts=1374541378&use_mirror=hivelocity
```

AMD64 (Note that this is a newer version)

```
wget --trust-server-name http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sbcl/sbcl/1.1.9/sbcl-1.1.9-x86-64-linux-binary.tar.bz2?r=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sbcl.org%2Fplatform-table.html&ts=1374541416&use_mirror=iweb
```

Answer (score 1):

in file which include to archive with sources and named INSTALL we see next text:

> end of section 2.1
>
> ...
>   Now you should have the same src/runtime/sbcl and output/sbcl.core
>   files that come with the binary distribution, and you can install
>   them as described in the section 1. "BINARY DISTRIBUTION".

the way for you are next:

1. download sbcl sources using any convenient way for you.
2. run shell terminal (may be window) and go to the sources archive path

   $ cd /path/to/sbcl-sources.tar.bz2
   $ tar -xjvf sbcl*.tar.bz2
   $ cd sbcl [TAB COMPLETE AND ENTER]
   $ emacs INSTALL

now you will see INSTALL file, which contains installation notes. As we will see in 2.1 section

> To build SBCL you need a working toolchain and a Common Lisp system
>   (see section 2.5 "Supported platforms").
>   You also need approximately 128 Mb of free RAM+swap.
>
> To build SBCL using alredy installed SBCL run

```
$sh make.sh # may be need execute rights. run 'chmod +x make.sh' and try again
```

and go next according instruction.

If you don't have existing sbcl instruction said next:

> If you don't already have an SBCL binary installed as "sbcl" on your
>   system, you'll need to tell make.sh what Lisp to use as the
>   cross-compilation host. For example, to use CMUCL (assuming has
>   been installed under its default name "lisp") as the
>   cross-compilation host:
>
> $ sh make.sh --xc-host='lisp -batch -noinit'

assuming supported lisp platforms see 2.5 section. Generally, if you attentively read INSTALL file you will able to do it easy and quickly. Have fun and happy new year.

Answer (score 1):

install the binary first
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sbcl/files/sbcl/1.2.7/sbcl-1.2.7

then install the latest version
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sbcl/files/sbcl/1.2.16/sbcl-1.2.16-source.tar.bz2/download?use_mirror=iweb&download=